# PHP switch an object whether a string or a number

Tags: php, json, object

Im trying to get something out of the json data that i have so this my json data

```
    $json = '
    {
        "type": {
            "image" : [
                {"data" : "PNG"}
            ],
            "title" : [
                {"value" : "OJKAOSKAOSK"}
            ],
            "text" : [
                {"value" : "asdsada"}
            ]
        }
    }';

    $form = json_decode($json);
```

Then make it an object with `json_decode();`

After that Im trying to do a switch like this:

```
    foreach ($form as $type) {
        print_r($type->image);
        switch($type) {
            case 'image':
                echo 'image_data';
            break;
            case 'text' :
                print_r('text_value');
            break;
            case 'title' :
                print_r('title_value');
            break;
            default:
                print_r('none');
            break;
        }
    }
```

The thing is I cant see this data using case 'string', but I can see the data with `$form->type->image` or `$type->image` is there a possibility to make a switch out of it with string as a case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way

```
 <?php 
foreach ($form->type as $key => $val) {
        echo $key;
        switch($key) {
            case 'image':
                echo 'image_data';
            break;
            case 'text' :
                print_r('text_value');
            break;
            case 'title' :
                print_r('title_value');
            break;
            default:
                print_r('none');
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

It should work the way you are expecting it to be.

Comment: wow this actually works! thanks alot! I forgot I can do something in `foreach` side damn my bad!

Comment: Mark my answer as solution (y).